# How to get the inserted row id in insert query using sqlite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

INSERT INTO Student (id, FirstName, LastName, SpouseName, DOB, GenderId, Email )  OUTPUT Inserted.id VALUES (hex( randomblob(4)) || '-' || hex( randomblob(2))|| '-' || '4' || substr( hex( randomblob(2)), 2) || '-'|| substr('AB89', 1 + (abs(random()) % 4) , 1) ||substr(hex(randomblob(2)), 2) || '-' || hex(randomblob(6)),?, ?, ?, ?, (SELECT ID FROM Gender WHERE Name ='Female'), ?;

OUTPUT Inserted.id ll retrieve last inserted row id in SQl.
But, Sqlite I don't Know what's instead of OUTPUT Inserted.id.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split this into two statements; first is your insert and then immediately after that `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` which will give you the inserted rows' id.

See the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) on how this works; and the [sql reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) for the function as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I too use the same way to get the last Inserted row id. Anyhow Thank u again.